# How to change appName by flavors

Tags: android, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

```kotlin
enum class FlavorDimension {
    contentType
}

enum class Flavor (val dimension : FlavorDimension, val applicationIdSuffix : String? = null) {
    dev(FlavorDimension.contentType, ".dev"),
    prod(FlavorDimension.contentType)
}

fun Project.configureFlavors(
    commonExtension: CommonExtension<*, *, *, *>
) {
    commonExtension.apply {
        flavorDimensions += FlavorDimension.contentType.name
        productFlavors {
            Flavor.values().forEach{
                create(it.name) {
                    dimension = it.dimension.name
                    if (this@apply is ApplicationExtension && this is ApplicationProductFlavor) {
                        if (it.applicationIdSuffix != null) {
                            this.applicationIdSuffix = it.applicationIdSuffix
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

reference: [nowinandroid](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/main/build-logic/convention/src/main/kotlin/com/google/samples/apps/nowinandroid/NiaFlavor.kt)

possible?

i want each flavor:

- devDubug: appName + "devDebug"
- devRelease: appName + "devRelease"
- prodDebug: appName + "prodDebug"
- prodRelease: appName